# How to configure WebStorm to recognise kebab-case class names when using CSS Modules with SASS

Tags: reactjs, sass, webstorm, css-modules

I recently started a project where they are using **camelCase** class names in the JSX, but **kebab-case** in the SCSS.

When Webpack builds the solution, the kebab-case class names are converted to camelCase by the `css-loader`.  WebStorm is showing code warnings for all the class names however in the JSX because it doesn't recognise this.

Is there a way to configure it to realise that they exist in kebab-case form and remove the warnings?  I don't want to just turn the rule off because it's quite useful to spot the classes that are actually missing from the SCSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to configure this in Webstorm; please vote for [WEB-28203](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28203) to be notified on any progress with this feature